# How to return the index number of the smallest percentage in the likehoods

Tags: java

```
public class Elections1 {

    public static int visit(String[] likelihoods){
        double smallestPer=1.00;
        int smallestIndex=0;

        //Go through each element inside likelihoods
        for(int i=0;i<likelihoods.length;i++){
            String likelihood = likelihoods[i];

            // Calculate the percentage
            int countOfOne = 0;

            //What to include here???

            double percentage = (double)countOfOne/likelihood.length();

            //Store the smallest value by comparing the smallest percentage
            if(percentage < smallestPer){
                smallestPer = percentage;
                smallestIndex = i; 
            }
        }

        //Return the index number
        return smallestIndex;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] likelihood={"1222","1122","1222"};

        System.out.println(visit(likelihood));
    }
}
```

I need to return the index number of the smallest percentage in the likehoods, what statement can I include in the "Calculate the percentage" for each likelihoods.length?

Comment: What are the strings `"1222","1122","1222"` supposed to represent?

Comment: Sorry about that. "1" represents some number of votes for candidate 1, and "2" represents votes for candidate 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the function to just find the smallest percentage in the array, and the array consists of percentages in the form of Strings, then you can just parse the Strings as Integers and compare them.

Assuming that what you want 1222, 1122 and 1222 to be is 12.22%, 11.22% and 12.22% respectively, then parsing the Strings to Integers and comparing them is enough.

That being said, you don't need to declare many of the variables that you actually declared.

```
public class Percentages {

  public static int visit(String[] likelihoods) {
    int smallestPer = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int smallestIndex = 0;

    //Go through each element inside likelihoods
    for (int i = 0; i < likelihoods.length; i++) {

      int likelihood = Integer.parseInt(likelihoods[i]);

      //Store the smallest value by comparing the smallest percentage
      if (likelihood < smallestPer) {
        smallestPer = likelihood;
        smallestIndex = i;
      }
      if (likelihood == 0) {
        return i;
      }
    }

    return smallestIndex;  
  }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] likelihood = {"1222","1122","1222"};

        System.out.println(visit(likelihood));
    }
}
```

This works for me. Is this what you want though?

Comment: Ohya, the parseInt can be used in this case. It's help, thank you!